# WP Custom Post Query - Nested

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type filter I need to compare categories to sectors, It works if I don't use my foreach loop but I need the for each loop to get each of the values. The values are entered via check box using acf. For some reason the below does not work, I have looked everywhere but can't seem to get it to work.

```
foreach ($thecategories as $thecategory) {
        if($thecategory != 0) {
            $value = $thecategory;
        } else {
            $value = '';
            
        }

        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => 'category',
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ];
    
    
    }

    // GET ALL SECTORS SELECTED
    foreach ($thesectors as $thesector) {
        if($thesector != 0) {
            $value = $thesector;
        } else {
            $value = '';
            
        }
        $meta_query2[] = [
            'key' => 'sector',
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ];
        }

    $reviewArgs = array(
        'post_type'     => 'case_studies',
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
         array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                $meta_query,
    ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            $meta_query2,

    ),
    
    
    ),

    );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$thecategories  =  $settings['category'];
    $thesectors     =  $settings['sector'];
    
    // $cm_metaq = array();
    $CatQuery = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
    foreach($thecategories as $thecategory){
        $CatQuery[] = array('key' => 'category', 'value' => $thecategory, 'compare' => 'LIKE');
    }
    // $sectorQuery = array();
    $sectorQuery = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
    foreach($thesectors as $thesector){
        $sectorQuery[] = array('key' => 'sector', 'value' =>$thesector,  'compare' => 'LIKE');
    }


    $reviewArgs = array(
        'post_type'     => 'case_studies',
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        $CatQuery
    ),
    array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        $sectorQuery
    )
        
    ),

    );
```